# Vectors and straight lines

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I was solving some vectors exercises but I came across with some doubts about them. I don't know how to do these exercises, so I would appreciate some help. Thanks.

1) Find a parametric and a vectorial equation for a straight line parallel to the $Y$ axis and knowing that it intersects the straight line defined by $2y+3=0$

2) Let the straight line be $L': (x;y)=2+3t, -1+kt$, determine, if possible, $k$, which belongs to the real numbers, so that $L'$ is
A) perpendicular to the $X$ axis
B) perpendicular to the vector $(-7;1)$

Comment: Okay so let's look at the first one. It asks for a line that's parallel to the $y$-axis, so in other words it should be of the form $x=\text{constant}$. And it should also intersect the line $y=\frac{-3}{2}$. But all lines of the form $x=\text{constant}$ cross this line! Weird ... So you could just put $x=0$, or any number ...

Comment: And how can I write that as a parametric and vectorial equation?