# Vectorial and parametric equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, vectors

I was solving some vectors exercises but I came across with some doubts about them. I don't know how to do this exercise, so I would appreciate some help. Thanks.

1) Find a parametric and a vectorial equation for a straight line parallel to the $y$ axis and knowing that it intersects the straight line defined by $2y+3=0$

I mean, I know that $2y+3=0$ is equal to $y=-3÷2$, so any line parallel to $y$ will intersect it. But I don't know how to write it as a parametric and vectorial equation.

Comment: Kudos for separating out one of the two separate questions that you asked in [your previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3184636/265466), but you really should edit your questions to add context instead of reposting them.

Comment: Excuse me, but I edited it. If you compare both of them, you should realize that I added some information about my doubt.

Comment: You added a couple of sentences to this new copy of the question that you should instead have edited into the original one.

Comment: Ok. I'll take your advice.

Comment: Now, can you help me with my question?